Simulators gone after XCode update
I am running Version 15.4 (15F31d). Yesterday I installed an update, opened XCode again and there was a message like "Simulator needs update". I clicked OK, nothing happened. Now, all my simulators are gone, and I cannot get them back. I restarted XCode already as well as my computer.
Here, before I installed the updated, I was able to select different simulators

This is how it looks like when I click on "Manage Run Destinations...". All of them have the selection "Show run destination: Always"

Under the Product - Destination menu I have Show all run destinations selected.
What I do not understand is, that I can start the Simulator App

But XCode does not recognize any simulator...
When I connect my iPhone, it does not show up here

but I can see it here

I also tried running it from the command line
$ xcrun simctl list devices

which gave me
    iPhone Xs (6723AC4A-4B19-46F5-BAE5-6C3DF2BC253B) (Shutdown)
    iPhone SE (3rd generation) (CA9C9B3E-B542-412C-B845-71A0B7D9D797) (Booted)
    iPhone SE (3rd generation) (DB2FF536-D849-4786-B3BD-8FB7068F212A) (Shutdown)
    iPhone 15 (B039DEC7-D015-4313-A7D9-2CB2324E232B) (Shutdown)
    iPhone 15 Plus (797BBF51-A7A9-4F41-A532-424B775AB14D) (Shutdown)
    iPhone 15 Pro (36E9933C-D4FB-4818-B4EA-F3ADE9BC5AFF) (Shutdown)
    iPhone 15 Pro Max (4CDB180C-79F2-4827-B2AB-256F1812FE98) (Shutdown)
    iPad Air (5th generation) (AE3E77BB-137D-42EC-B2C0-2179320216F6) (Shutdown)
    iPad (10th generation) (8FD9CB57-CEBA-4570-B7F0-FDEFAAF20683) (Shutdown)
    iPad mini (6th generation) (0B6E1473-1864-49B0-BB91-4A2C4F692424) (Shutdown)
    iPad Pro (11-inch) (4th generation) (6B9E5069-A52A-4772-96D9-68FFCF496BEC) (Shutdown)
    iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (6th generation) (1E45FFF9-E844-4EFC-9938-59C80F8721D7) (Shutdown)

Then I run
$ yarn ios --udid "CA9C9B3E-B542-412C-B845-71A0B7D9D797"

Which returned
error Failed to build iOS project. "xcodebuild" exited with error code '70'. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening 'Foo.xcworkspace'.
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace Foo.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme Foo -destination id=CA9C9B3E-B542-412C-B845-71A0B7D9D797

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES


2024-07-25 15:38:32.989 xcodebuild[2255:51186] Writing error result bundle to /var/folders/_j/5k_qtwqn5k39srgfty_40xmc0000gp/T/ResultBundle_2024-25-07_15-38-0032.xcresult
xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
        { id:CA9C9B3E-B542-412C-B845-71A0B7D9D797 }

    Ineligible destinations for the "Foo" scheme:
        { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device, error:iOS 17.5 is not installed. To use with Xcode, first download and install the platform }

error Command failed with exit code 1.

Why can't I run my app on a simulator anymore? My iOS Deployment target is set to 13...

Which XCode you are using? If it is the latest one it should work with  iOS 12 and above

@CodeChanger as I wrote: Version 15.4 (15F31d)

There is a difference between the simulators and the SDK. You've got the simulators; you've proved that. What you don't have is the SDK. That is what the little popover is asking you to download, with the Get button that it shows.

So tap that Get button! Then go do something else. The download may take a while, depending on the speed of your Internet connection; and afterwards, even when the download has finished, there will be a very long delay before the installation finishes. But eventually it will complete and you'll be ready to go.

What I do not get is, I downloaded SDK 15, nothing showed up. Only after download SDK 17.5 it started to work again...

Yes, because Xcode can't work at all without it. It used to be part of Xcode; now it is a separate download. So the Xcode update was much smaller than it used to be; perhaps you noticed that? That's because the "big" part of it is this separate download.

Ah, okay... No need to delete everything that was already there though. I had it all setup, and the update deleted all of it. thanks for clarifying!
